# PCL Header to Sensor_msg convertion problem

Tags: c++, pcl, camera, ros-fuerte, camera-depth-points

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Guys,

I have this code snippet (I wrote it):

```
#include "depth_image_proc.h"
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <image_geometry/pinhole_camera_model.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>

generatePCL::generatePCL(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& depth_msg,          
        const sensor_msgs::CameraInfoConstPtr& info_m)                         
{
    cloud_msg.header = depth_msg->header;                                      
    cloud_msg.height = depth_msg->height;                                      
    cloud_msg.width  = depth_msg->width;                                       
    cloud_msg.is_dense = false;
    cloud_msg.points.resize(cloud_msg.height * cloud_msg.width);                                                 
    convert(depth_msg);
}
```

Where cloud_msg is defined as:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud_msg;
```

But after I run the code I get this error:

```
depth_image_proc.cpp: In constructor ‘generatePCL::generatePCL(const ImageConstPtr&, const CameraInfoConstPtr&)’:
depth_image_proc.cpp:16:19: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘pcl::PCLHeader’ and ‘const _header_type {aka const std_msgs::Header_<std::allocator<void> >}’)
  cloud_msg.header = depth_msg->header;
                   ^
```

Is there a library I am missing? Or a new format?
This code was running in Fuerte, and now I am trying to make it run in Indigo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201465/pcl-header-to-sensor_msg-convertion-problem/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2015-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There were incompatible changes to the way ROS uses PCL between Groovy and Hydro.

Please consult the [Hydro migration guide](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration#PCL) for details.

**EDIT**: since Groovy there is a new [pcl_conversions](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_conversions) package that may help with your problem. The [API doc is here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/pcl_conversions/html/namespacepcl__conversions.html).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2015-01-21**:
I still can't find the way to convert sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& to pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ
Every function I sue (such as pcl::toPCL) always gives me an error that there is not matching function.